# How to overwrite local files with a specific Heroku release version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I made a series of small commits to an Heroku app without realizing something broke. I was able to `rollback` to previous versions and found the last working version.

I'm not sure what the proper git wordage is here (I guess either `clone` or `pull`). To clarify I want to replace all of my local machine app directory with the last working version on Heroku.

```
heroku releases
v29  Rollback to v16                        -email-  2014/10/25 12:50:44 (~ 3h ago)
v28  Rollback to v17                        -email-  2014/10/25 12:49:53 (~ 3h ago)
v27  Rollback to v16                        -email-  2014/10/25 12:49:01 (~ 3h ago)
v26  Rollback to v15                        -email-  2014/10/25 12:48:29 (~ 3h ago)
v25  Rollback to v13                        -email-  2014/10/25 12:47:44 (~ 3h ago)
v24  Rollback to v18                        -email-  2014/10/25 12:44:10 (~ 3h ago)
v23  Rollback to v21                        -email-  2014/10/25 02:33:09 (~ 13h ago)
v22  Rollback to v20                        -email-  2014/10/25 02:31:22 (~ 13h ago)
v21  Set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY config vars  -email-  2014/10/21 23:27:55
v20  Set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID config vars      -email-  2014/10/21 23:27:33
v19  Set S3_BUCKET config vars              -email-  2014/10/21 23:27:17
v18  Deploy 2f2a538                         -email-  2014/10/21 13:03:33
v17  Deploy a957bed                         -email-  2014/10/21 12:52:06
v16  Deploy f707b5e                         -email-  2014/10/19 18:30:27
v15  Remove BUILDPACK_URL config vars       -email-  2014/10/19 18:29:30
```

So `v16` is the last working commit. I want my local app folder to be the code of `v16` which is `f707b5e`.

I tried many ways and, every attempt just reproduced the latest commit.

1. How do I get the specific release `v16` / `f707b5e`?
2. How do I remove/discard all releases after `v16`?

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset --hard <yourCommitHash>
heroku git:clone -a <appName>
```

This just worked for me :o